# Is it possible to hide email and script url in formmail form?

Tags: javascript

I get a lot of spam email from my web form that uses Matt's formmail script. I tried putting a reCaptcha on the page, but I'm still getting spam. I thought maybe if I hid the email and formmail script in an external js file it might cut down on the spam. So I was using the values from an external js file and doing a document.write to use the variables. Problem is the cgi complains I didn't use the recipient. It does get both the url and the recipient email address correctly as I've done an onload alert that displays both perfectly. wondering why it won't submit with the email. from the js file I have:

```
var myURL = "www.mycompany.com/cgi-bin/formmail.cgi";
var myOwnEmail = "support@mycompany.com";
```

in my document.write I have:

```
document.write('<form name="myForm" action="'+myURL+'" onSubmit="return checkForm()" method="POST"><br/>');

document.write('<input type="hidden" name="recipient" value="'+myOwnEmail+'">');
```

Or should I just be using some other method to prevent spam?

Comment: Send the email server-side, not client-side

Comment: Why don't you put the mail address on the serverside and send mail there? (e.g. php). Aww, @CristianTraìna was faster

Comment: I'm using the Matt's formmail script my web service provided so i can't change the script to hard-code my email address. was hoping to not have to roll my own perl script just to hide the email. Actually surprised it doesn't recognize the email since it seems to read the url to the script just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you're not going to be able to prevent spam, not really. That's why we have such sophisticated anti-spam measures nowadays.

But you can certainly improve matters by preventing entities from simply scraping the target email address from your website, by implementing all of this on the server, rather than in the web browser. Then the email address won't even be visible to bots.

That doesn't prevent them from submitting spam *via your form*, of course, but then your captcha ought to at least help with that.

To the best of my knowledge, it's been a *long* time (decades) since browser calls to formmail.cgi have been common practice.